# Google Sign In method with Firebase not working through version control shared project in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, firebase, google-signin

I have a team working on a project which uses Firebase for storing data and Google Sign in for authenticating users and their own stored data.

The problem is that everything works fine on my computer when I run the application through Android Studio (tried on 3 mobile phones), but when I share my code with my team through Git, they cannot sign in for some unknown reason. Then I've built an APK file and suddenly it all worked (they managed to run application on their phones).

Can anyone explain what is the main cause of this problem and how could I possibly edit the project to deliver a working project to my teammates on Git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your teammates should add a SHA fingerprint to your project in the firebase console. You can do that in your project's settings -> general and "ADD FINGERPRINT"